# Port 25 is blocked trying to send CDO email from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, networking, cdo.message

I have a VBA script to send email from Excel.

The script worked yesterday from my hotel; however, today from home on my home network, I get this error:

> "The transport failed to connect to the server."

My home network uses Google wifi points and connects VIA Comcast Xfinity. If I set up a hotspot from my phone using the AT&T network it works fine. Would that mean this port is blocked either on my home network or at XFinity?

Script is below:

```
Dim Mail As New Message
Dim Config As Configuration
Set Config = Mail.Configuration

Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
Config(cdoSendUserName) = "****"
Config(cdoSendPassword) = "****"
Config.Fields.Update

Mail.To = Config(cdoSendUserName)
Mail.From = Config(cdoSendUserName)
Mail.Subject = "Subject"
Mail.TextBody = "Body"

On Error Resume Next

Mail.Send

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "There was an error"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Secure email (cdoSMTPUseSLL) does not use port 25. You should read the GMail documentation about how to configure for SMTP, which will give you the proper port.

Comment: Hah!  That was easy enough.  Wonder why it worked from other networks but not from my home network...